# Can I access Facebook status history in an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is there any way I can get user Facebook status history in my iPhone app?

Can anyone guide me or post a link to a tutorial? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 minutes of googling landed me here, seems to be a fair starting point: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: the problem is that it does not define how to get our status history. you can only post trough it.